# Is it safe to delete all swap partitions?

Tags: debian, swap

More explicitly:

If it safe to shut down a system, boot from a live CD, delete all disk swap partitions, and boot the system?

This is in follow up to *[How to safely turn off swap permanently and reclaim the space? (on Debian Jessie)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224156/how-to-safely-turn-off-swap-permanently-on-debian-jessie)*.

I thought not Debian, or at least Ubuntu (and descendants) will automatically find all swap partitions on all mounted-at-boot disks and allocate swap correctly by default.

The post asking how to turn off swap has many answer posts that have involved, multi-step processes to turn off swap.

Is simply removing the swap partitions not recommended?

Comment: Why shutdown? swap off, then edit /etc/fstab and remove swap partition. You may need the live CD to resize other partition into where swap was.

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the swap partitions the system will fail to find them when it next boots. This is a non-fatal error, but you would be better also commenting out (or removing) the corresponding swap lines in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: So the system installer take's care of detecting and setting up swap partitions. Implying installing on a system that does not have swap partitions will not setup swap. Correct?

Comment: @ThorSummoner if you don't have a swap partition then you won't have swap. I don't understand what you're getting at, though

Comment: Since you mentioned Debian, I believe I saw in the install notes that performing the install on a system with less than 256MB of RAM required swap. So you will be required to dedicate some space for a swap partition at the partitioning step.  You don't have to define one if you have more memory though.  During a new install the text installer will give you a warning if you don't have a swap part defined, but you can safely ignore/skip it.